# PHP application in sub directory keeps redirecting to main site

Tags: htaccess

I've got a PHP script which I have setup in a subdirectory (`public_html/phpscript`) but whenever I try to access it via `www.example.com/phpscript` I get redirected to the main site with a 404 page not found.

The main site is a WordPress site with cloudflare enabled and wp-rocket plugin

Here is the main site `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]

# Performace optimization
# BEGIN Compress text files
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/xml text/css text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml application/xhtml+xml application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rdf+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/truetype font/opentype
</ifModule>
# END Compress text files

# BEGIN Expire headers
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 31536000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 31536000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 31536000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 31536000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 31536000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 31536000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 31536000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 31536000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 31536000 seconds"
</ifModule>
# END Expire headers

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /staging/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /staging/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch ".(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch ".(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch ".(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch ".(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>

  <filesMatch ".(woff|woff2|ttf|otf|eot)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000 private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Cache-Control Headers
<FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler proxy:fcgi://sociplat-php73
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I don't know much about the wp-rocket plugin.
In order not to get a 404 error, you need a index.php in your directory. I literally just tried it.

Comment: Is `phpscript` the filename (ie. `phpscript.php`) or the subdirectory? Where is WordPress installed? What is the URL you are using for your WP site? You appear to have 2 (possibly conflicting) front-controllers?

Comment: The wrodpres site is located in public_html/ and the phpscript is located in public_html/phpscript and each one has it own index.php file